# PDO - Join em uma função

Tags: mysql, pdo

Estou inserindo uma nova consulta em um sistema ja funcional, porem não estou conseguindo entender como inserir um **JOIN** , vi que existe a Função, so não consigo implantar.

Tentei executar assim

```
$query_cliente  = QB::table('tbl_reclamacoes')->join('tbl_usuarios','id_usuarios','id_cadastro_reclamacoes')->where('id_reclamacoes','=',$get_id);
```

Mas não funcionou, ja tentei de outras formas, mas acho que não entendi

```
 public function join($table, $key, $operator = null, $value = null, $type = 'inner')
{
    if (!$key instanceof \Closure) {
        $key = function ($joinBuilder) use ($key, $operator, $value) {
            $joinBuilder->on($key, $operator, $value);
        };
    }


    $joinBuilder = $this->container->build('\\Pixie\\QueryBuilder\\JoinBuilder', array($this->connection));
    $joinBuilder = & $joinBuilder;       
    $key($joinBuilder);
    $table = $this->addTablePrefix($table, false);       
    $this->statements['joins'][] = compact('type', 'table', 'joinBuilder');
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Porque não fazer o `JOIN` diretamente na _query_ SQL?

Comment: Por ser em PDO as outras classes de WHERE , ORDER BY e etc ja funcionam assim, então pela logica ja que tem a classe de JOIN, gostaria de deixar como padrão, ate poderia trocar, ja ate coloquei funcionando, mas assim acho que começa a poluir o que ja esta pronto